# How to capture url of a new page selenium scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to develop a web-scraping project in which I scrape a website called startup India in which you can use for connecting with startups and here I click based on some filters I selected and click on every startup and when I clicked on every startup I have to go inside that startup and scrape it but the problem here is in the console I'm not seeing the URL's which I want to scrape.

Here is the code:

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import logging
class ProductSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "product_spider"
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.startupindia.gov.in/']
    start_urls = ['https://www.startupindia.gov.in/content/sih/en/search.html?industries=sih:industry/advertising&states=sih:location/india/andhra-pradesh&stages=Prototype&roles=Startup&page=0']

    def __init__(self):
        cwd = os.getcwd()
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/RAJ/PycharmProjects/WebCrawler/WebCrawler/WebCrawler/spiders/chromedriver.exe")


    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)


        next = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div#persona-results a')
        logging.info(next)

        for i in next:
            try:
                logging.info(i.click())
                logging.info(response.url)

                # get the data and write it to scrapy items
            except:
                print("Yolo")
```

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the website is opening the startup screen in a new tab, so you would have to switch to the current tab

`self.driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])`

or you find the URL by Xpath `"//*[@id='persona-results']//a[@class='img-wrap']"` and open it directly without clicking, that will be faster

Comment: Hey Individual this did improve my code for working faster but didn't solve my problem but thanks anyway and hope you can figure out :)